# Windows 8 running out of memory?

Tags: windows-8, memory, task-manager, resource-monitor

About an hour after startup I get a message box saying windows is low on memory, I've got 16GB ram and as far as I can see I should be using no more than 20% of my memory from the applications in task manager

However when I look in task manager the performance screen says I'm using 13.9GB at around 85%. so far I've been restarting it but it is becoming quite a pain

I don't know my way around resource monitor but in there I am only using 15ish% physical but 100% commit charge?

[image: resource manager]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I'm using Windows 8 Pro 64bit, this issue wasn't happening a month ago on windows 7 (home premium I think) 64 bit

I have now closed everything and gone through some applications in task manager, I closed BCMWLTRAY.exe which Google says is a broadcomm application which is fine... this has now taken usage down to 12%

Should I investigate the possibility of it being malware? or could it just be incompatible with Windows 8?

Comment: BCMWLTRAY.exe is known to cause it under Windows 7. It generates a lot of modified memory. You can see this in the Resource Monitor (large orange graph). Try to updaet the Broadcom driver and look if this fixes it.

Comment: In Task Manager, in the Performance Tab, if you click Memory, what does it say in the "Memory Composition" area when you mouse over it? (In use, modified, stand by, free).

Comment: @Mark allen Most of it was modified,
I'm just updating drivers for broadcom though because there are a lot of other people who have had similar issues with it, thanks magicandre

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/152924/getting-running-low-on-memory-errors-on-windows-7-64-bit-with-8gb-ram 
this person had the same issue, thanks for the help

Comment: @Alex if your question is answered and your problem is solved please consider marking your question as such.