# How to find the source of the low on memory error. Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, memory, drivers, task-manager

Windows 8.1 64bit runs on Asus laptop with 8Gb of RAM and NVidia chip. McAffee antivirus was installed from the very begging. All drivers are up to date. Recently I start getting low on memory error.

According to the task manager, at that time, 98% RAM was consumed, McAffee consumed the most of RAM - 200 Mb and according to the task manager, 200 Mb was 25% out of the total memory!!!

**The question**: Who has consumed the rest 7.2 Gb of RAM ? I suspect that maybe some drivers, like in this case: [Getting 'running low on memory errors' on Windows 7 64-bit with 8GB RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/152924/getting-running-low-on-memory-errors-on-windows-7-64-bit-with-8gb-ram).

But I do not like an idea to spend a week of reverting every single driver. Is there a way to find the cause of this problem??? Maybe some external tool could help?

Comment: [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can help locate which process is using your memory.  We will need more information.  Does this problem happen when you use a minimal start-up configuration?

Comment: In addition to what @Ramhound suggested, [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) can be useful in determining what that memory is used as, and can help expose non-process memory usage (e.g. drivers, cache).

Comment: looks like you have a driver issue. Check this: http://superuser.com/a/674725/174557

Answer (score 1):

As Ramhound suggests, Process Explorer will give a decent picture of what is running and what is consuming your memory.

Bear in mind that you might have some dodgy software that is causing a memory leak (using up memory and not releasing it cleanly to be reused by other processes). For example, I recently had a memory leak while running a game... when changing maps on BF4, there was a 50-75% chance that a memory leak would start... over the next few minutes, my memory utilization would gradually ramp up to 92-98% and a reboot was required.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2009/02/15/identifying-memory-leak-with-process-explorer-and-windbg.aspx) might help you identify if there is a memory leak, and what processes are responsible.

Comment: Interesting. A memory leak that is not resolved by closing the offending process (i.e. a system memory leak rather than a process one) is particularly nasty. It's typically caused by either a bug in the OS itself, or one of its drivers (graphics drivers are a particularly big offender in this respect).

Comment: In this case, it was a problem with a certain range of ATI cards (Radeon HD5xxx-HD7xxx ranges)... AMD were adamant that the problem was with the game (or possibly OpenGL/DirectX/etc), but it was clearly with something low-level. Having upgraded my gfx card, I thankfully no longer have the problem, but it was never actually resolved.